# Passing attributes from parent to child Gutenberg Blocks

Tags: wordpress, attributes, parent-child, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

How to pass the parent attributes or to pass some props in the inner child block?

```js
<InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={[ 'groupama-blocks/block-08']}/>
```

For example I'd like to add this block attributes to block 08 that I will add as a inner block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PASSING DATA FROM PARENT TO CHILD GUTENBERG**

*PARENT*

```
const {useSelect, dispatch, select} = wp.data;

edit: (props) => {
    const {
        clientId
    } = props;

    var children = select('core/block-editor').getBlocksByClientId(clientId).[0].innerBlocks;
    children.forEach(function(child){
        dispatch('core/block-editor').updateBlockAttributes(child.clientId, {label: 'Hello'})
    });
```

*CHILD*

```
let parent = select('core/block-editor').getBlockParents(clientId);
const parentAttributes = select('core/block-editor').getBlockAttributes(parent);
console.log(parentAttributes); // Block Attributes
console.log(props.attributes.label); // Passing Props
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this example! I was working on something in the opposite direction - adding or removing children when something in the parent changes - but this example helped me understand `dispatch` so I could accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 3):

Block context is a Wordpress feature used in "registerBlockType", which allows ancestor blocks to provide values to descendant blocks.

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/